# GWT Chrome issue with anchors inside HTML widgets

Tags: html, google-chrome, gwt

I'm having a Chrome only issue when adding anchor tags for internal links inside an HTML widget.  This may sound quite unimportant but it's quite annoying for myself and many users.

When a page is loaded, if the links are middle-clicked or Ctrl-clicked the 1st time, they only open in a new tab/window like they should, but the 2nd time they act as though they were left clicked and use the same tab/window.  For some reason this problem doesn't happen when I use Hyperlink or Anchor widgets.  It also isn't an issue in Firefox or IE8.

I've verified that the final HTML of the Hyperlinks and my manually scripted tags are exactly the same.  I applied the same styles to the HTML widget to do this.  I even tried creating a Hyperlink and calling toString() to generate the HTML, but the bug still occurs.

Does anybody know why this could be happening or have any ideas of how to remedy it?  This is a situation where I can't use Widgets so I need to create the tag HTML manually.  I'm not a GWT expert, but I don't understand how the compiled code be handling the Hyperlink and Anchor widgets differently than the ones inside the HTML widgets.  Any incite into this could be helpful.

I'd be interested in knowing if anybody else could reproduce this as well.  I'm running Chrome 23.0.1271.97 and GWT-2.5.0.  I know this happens in older versions of Chrome and GWT because it's been a problem for a while, at least since GWT-2.4.

Uninteresting nuances:
If there are two different links inside the same HTML, they bug will happen independently.  Meaning that you can middle-click each one, and they will both work correctly, just not the 2nd time.  Refreshing the page also resets them so the bug won't happen on the next middle-click.  I also found that if the same link is twice contained in the HTML widget, they actually wont work independently.  Meaning middle-clicking one will cause the other to incorrectly handle it's 1st middle click.

Comment: FYI: `Hyperlink` listens to click events, detects whether it's "normal-clicked" or not (browser/platform-dependent) and if that's the case, call `History.setItem()` and `preventDefault()` the click event (and otherwise does nothing to let the browser handle the link and open it in a new tab/window).

Comment: Are you using #hashtags in your links at all?

Please provide an example of the anchor html in question.

Comment: Yes I'm adding the hash tag to the begining.  Here's the HTML:  <a href="#page=Asset&assetId=124">Asset-124</a>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just finished debugging this. It is not a GWT issue but a Chrome issue.

I created a bug report: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=177502

You can reproduce using this simple HTML page:`<!DOCTYPE html>
<a href="#local">LOCAL</a>`

Comment: Yea you're right, but somehow GWT gets around it with its Hyperlink and Anchor widgets.